# Setting LocationManager to default accuracy

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

My app uses  `significantLocationChanges` but for a short amount of time I need to use the GPS, so I set the accuracy to `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` and `startUpdatingLocation` after a short time I `stopUpdatingLocation`.
Since I will still be monitoring significant location changes I dont want to have `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` but a less accurate, the default one, so the battery doesn`t drain, which one is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The full set of valid values are...

```
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

Depending on your application's needs you'll want to select one of the les accurate settings - namely TenMetres, HundredMetres, Kilometer or ThreeKilometers.

Comment: so by default, the Location Manager, at what accuracy is set?

Comment: The default is kCLLocationAccuracyBest